# Using node.js to run application during weekdays

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mean-stack, scheduler

I am creating a web based application that I would like to only be able to run during the weekdays from 9:00 AM to 5:00 PM. I do not want my users to be able to perform any functions during before or after business hours and on weekends.

I am wondering if someone could point me in the right direction in how to proceed with this. Is there a way to do this in Node.js? The application allows users to post and upload videos, very simple application. I am using the MEAN stack, MongoDB, Express.js, AngularJS and Node.js

Comment: this can only be done through server code, what are you using: asp.net?

Comment: write a middleware for this and inject it before any request and check for weekdays if not weekday then send an response with proper message we serve you only on weekdays.

Comment: Do you already have a router solution set up and working for the site? If so, do the logic in there. - var d = new Date() ... compare date here. if( not working hours ) directPageToNonWorkingHoursPage(); else { directToPageRequested(); }      If you don't have a server side routing solution already, then in the client side you could just include a single JavaScript file that every single webpage had a src to and a

Comment: also from there, implement a function that checks the [something].pathname value or the [something].hash and in that logic that runs check the date and proceed from there

Comment: @Frank_Vr – The question says node.js. Twice.

Answer (score 2):

In your express routes, add something like the following code before all of the other routes.

```
router.use(function (req, res, next) {
    var date = new Date();
    if(date.getDay > 0 && date.getDay < 6 && date.getHours() > 9 && date.getHours < 17){
        next();
    }else{
        res.redirect('/offlinepage');
    }
});
```

All your user's request will pass through this middleware before getting to the other routes, and if the time/date criteria aren't satisfied you can redirect them to your offline page

Comment: Thank you for your answer! This was actually the logic I ended up using but instead of Node.js I used it in my AngularJS controllers and rerouted it to a closed page using the getDay and getHours function in a conditional. It does the trick!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone for your input. Instead of using Node.js, I used AngularJS instead. Below is one of my controllers as an example. I used the same logic in all the other

```
myApp.controller("AddVideoController", ["$scope", "$window", "VideoService", function($scope, $window, VideoService){ 
   var day = VideoService.checkDay();
   var hour = VideoService.checkHour();

   if((day == 0 || day == 6) || (hour > 17 || hour < 9 )){
      //reroute to closed page
      $window.location.href = '/views/closed.html'; 
   }else{
      //perform rest of code
    }
```

And in my VideoService Factory here are the checkHour and checkDay functions

```
myApp.factory("VideoService", ["$http", "$window", function($http, $window){
  var checkDay = function(){
    var day = new Date();
    var result = day.getDay();
    return result;
  };

  var checkHour = function(){
    var hour = new Date();
    var result = hour.getHours();
    return result;
  };

  return{
    checkDay: checkDay,
    checkHour: checkHour
   }
}
```

This really seemed to work and do the trick!